# Clojure: Why do I get StackOverflowError?

Tags: clojure

```clj
(defn abs [int]
  (if (neg? int) (* -1 int) int))

(defn move [v]
  (let [[x y z] v]
    (cond
      (> x (abs y)) (map + v [0 1 1])
      (or
        (and (= x y) (pos? x) (pos? y))
        (> y (abs x))) (map + v [-1 0 1])
      (or
        (and (= (abs x) y) (neg? x) (pos? y))
        (and (> y x) (> (abs x) y))) (map + v [0 -1 1])
      :else (assoc [x y z] 0 (inc x) 2 (inc z))
      ;:else (map + v [1 0 1])
      )))


(last (take-while (fn [[x y z]] (< z 2000)) (iterate move [1 0 2])))
```

The above code constructs the spiraling integers with their respective Cartesian co-ordinates. Note the commented out part `:else (map + v [1 0 1])` vs `:else (assoc [x y z] 0 (inc x) 2 (inc z))`. Both of them work. But for large values say, `z < 10000`, I get:
`Error printing return value (StackOverflowError) at clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq (LazySeq.java:51). null`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is lazy, it's not evaluates the mapping at once, but rather stacks mapping functions until the resulting collection really needs to be realized. So when you need the first item, it would do `(+ v1 (+ v2 (+ v3 ..)`, and so forth, and it would eventually blow the stack for large number of `map`s stacked.

small example:

```
(reduce (fn [acc _] (map + acc [1 1 1]))
        [0 0 0] (range 1000))
;; (1000 1000 1000)

(reduce (fn [acc _] (map + acc [1 1 1]))
        [0 0 0] (range 10000))
;; Error printing return value (StackOverflowError) at clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval (LazySeq.java:42).
;; null
```

what you can do, is to replace `map` with it's eager counterpart, `mapv`:

```
(reduce (fn [acc _] (mapv + acc [1 1 1]))
        [0 0 0] (range 10000))
;; [10000 10000 10000]
```

Comment: Then why does the above code work for large values? There are three other almost identical `map` functions. What is special about the `map` in the `:else` part?

Comment: nothing special, since any of your `map` calls are stacked over each other, depending on the condition. So really it could throw from any of them.

Comment: Yes but the current working code has three of those same `map` functions, and they do not produce `overflow` error, even for very large values.